# PhantomJS sending keys to wrong input

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I have a Java application with selenium and phantomJS.

I built a test to login to an application. There is a step where I send the username and password keys, like so:

```
this.usernameField.sendKeys(username);
this.passwordField.sendKeys(password);
```

The fields are identified by ID.

The test works fine in Chrome, but in PhantomJS, both keys are sent to the username input.

For example: username: John - Password: banana

- In Chrome: Username: [John]   Password: [banana]
- In PhantomJS: Username: [Johnbanana]   Password: []

If I put a break point and wait after sending the username but before sending the password, then release it, it results in: "Username: [John]   Password: [banana]"

Sometimes I get "[Johnban] [ana]" or "[Johnbana] [na]" and so on.

Is this a known bug? I was using PhantomJS from **org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.4.0** just fine, but now I had to update versions to **org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59** and include **com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.4.4**.

How can I fix this without putting "wait" all over the code?

Comment: Depending on what "this" is here, it really sounds like a problem with these calls being made asynchronously by phantomJS.  Very strange that it would cause this, but I'm guessing the pointer/cursor position doesn't get updated properly.  It could also be some odd client-side validation code which isn't keeping up with the typing and doing something odd.  (If that's the case try sending chars instead with some wait time in between.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, in this particular case, switching the order to "password" first and then "username" fixed the issue.

Just to be clear, the page in question is Jira.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. You may have the same situation even in your Chrome if your page loads faster than the code execution. It seems like it is the case in your PhantomJS.

What you can do is to avoid wait everywhere in your code, wrap the waiting behavior in some class, wait until the element is visible and take the action in your upper layers.

You can use [presenceOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to check and get the element

```java
public class ElementFinder {
       public WebElement find(By locator) {
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
          WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
          return element;
       }
    }
```

Then find and call your sendKeys. To avoid casting (you should) WebElement, you can use generics, just wanted to give the idea in the example.

Also, you can have a look for **PageObjects** by Martin Fowler [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html). It makes it easy for those kinds of operations like I suggested above wrapping InputElements and its behaviors in some object, also for the rest of the page.

Comment: I am using PageObjects but I fail to see a way to seamlessly add the wait functionality to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting in a loop that checks if the entered value by your script is what you expected? Sometimes this will do the trick.

Comment: I did, with fluent wait. It does work, but the whole issue is that I wanted to avoid putting "waits" in the code. But yeah, that's a way to fix it.